# Multiple files concatenation using ffmpeg by the use of GPU Hardware acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to concatenate multiple mp4, h264 encoded files into single one together with speed up filter, using GPU HW acceleration. I am using Debian 10 Buster 64bit, and the card I am using is Nvidia Gainward GTX960.

I have installed CUDA, together with Nvidia driver and configured ffmpeg with the following parameters:

```
./configure --enable-nonfree -–enable-cuda-sdk –enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64`
```

The problem is, I believe, that GPU is not working at 100%, so the concatenation takes quite a long time.

The command I am using to concatenate files and speeding them up:

```
./ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -f concat -i mylist.txt -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -y -filter:v 'setpts='0.0625'*PTS' -an merged.mp4
```

Output of nvidia-smi while the above command is being executed:

[image: Image.png]

```
ffmpeg version: ffmpeg version N-102801-gb74beba9a9
CUDA version: 11.2
Nvidia driver version: 460.84
```

I have no idea what else can I do to speed up the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. From the command line you post, it seems you are running source videos through decoder and encoder. That is, reencoding. ¿Why?

If all you want is speed, concatenation, and compression is fine as-is, I think you can just pass-through the video frames. Same as the audio: `-c:v copy`.

Probably. :-)

Comment: Well, I found a topic in ffmpeg wiki 'How to speed up/slow down a video'. There is a clear statement that using the ​setpts video filter requires reencoding. Is it possible to speed up video without reencoding?

Comment: I don't know. But, to speed up a video you most probably drop some frames. If you drop some frames (e.g. an I frame), I think reencoding is necessary.

Comment: Hey @PabloH what would the full command for this? :)